# Intersect doesn't work between Lists

Tags: c#, visual-studio, equality

I have a little strange problem. 
 I use Visual Studio and I am developing a project with C#. 
I have two custom classes "Attr" and "FD" and I use lists that includes their objects e.g.

```
List<Attr> attrList = new List<Attr>();
List<FD> fdList = new List<FD>();
```

So when I try to find the intersection of two lists the result is not what I expect. To make it more simple I tried to Intersect similar Objects and the result is wrong again. What is going wrong?

This is the fd. It is an object of class FD. 
[image: this is the fd] 
This is the ff which is also an object of FD class. 
[image: this is ff]

As you can see these object contains exactly the same values. 
The method *GetLeft()* returns a list that contains objects of class Attr.

So when I try to find the intersection between those two lists (*fd.GetLeft()* and *ff.GetLeft()* ) the result is nothing (it should be a list that contains an Attr object "A").
[image: this is intersection]

What did I miss?

P.S. These screenshots are from the debugg mode in Visual Studio.

Comment: You have a custom class so what method are you using for EQUAL?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583793/custom-intersect-in-lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use `Intersect` I suggest implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>`, something like this :

```
public class FD
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

 static void Main()
    {
        List<FD> fdList1 = new List<FD>();
        fdList1.Add(new FD { Name = "a" });

        List<FD> fdList2 = new List<FD>();
        fdList2.Add(new FD { Name = "a" });

       IEnumerable<FD> fd = fdList1.Intersect<FD>(fdList2, new ComparerFd()).ToList();
    }
```

And the `CamparerFd` should be like this :

```
public class ComparerFd : IEqualityComparer<FD>
{

    public bool Equals(FD x, FD y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(FD obj)
    {
        if(obj == null) return 0;
        
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();//Or whatever way to get hash code
    }
}
```

Comment: Your implementation of `GetHashCode` is wrong, since just returning a random number does not return the same hash code for equal objects. Due to that, the `Intersect`-method will still not work, if it uses the hash code for fast comparisons (and I'd be pretty sure that it does). Generally, if not implementing `GetHashCode` correctly, It would be better to atleast return a constant value - this way, everything will work, and "only" be slow... In this specific case, just return `this.Name.GetHashCode()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you guys!! @Timitry. Problem solved!

Comment: `this.Name` does not exist in the `ComparerFd` class. I think you meant `return obj.Name.GetHashCode();`. I have used this approach and it worked. Also note you should check for and handle null: `return obj.Name == null ? 0 : obj.Name.GetHashCode();`

Comment: @SleekPanther thanks for the notes, updated in the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you created your own class, and did not override the `Equals`-method in that class, the `Intersect`-method will only compare the references of the objects, and not the properties.

Take the following, really simple class:

```
class MyClass
{
  int Value { get; set; }

  public MyClass(int value)
  {
    this.Value = value;
  }
}
```

Now, create two lists, with both containing one object. The properties of the objects are the same, but the instances are not:

```
  var list1 = new List<MyClass>
  {
    new MyClass(5)
  };

  var list2 = new List<MyClass>
  {
    new MyClass(5)
  };
```

So the following will happen:

```
  list1[0].Equals(list2[0]); // false
  list1.Intersect(list2); // No matches
```

If you want these methods to compare the properties of your `MyClass`-objects, implement `IEqualityComparer<MyClass>`, e.g. change the classes signature to:

```
class MyClass : IEqualityComparer<MyClass>
{
  ..
}
```

Alternatively, you can just override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, as then these methods will be called as default `IEqualityComparer`.

See the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/4469336) on how to properly override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.